# How to Consume Webservice - NOT using wsimport - Using Dependency Injection

Tags: java, web-services, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

Good evening guys,

I'm wondering how to Consume a Webservice without using WSIMPORT and injecting the service interface.

Let me be more specific what I was thinking about doing:

> Imagine we have project: project-ws
>
> which exports the interfaces and the DTO as follows

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://namespace", name = "ServiceName")
public interface Webservice {
    
    @WebMethod
    public @WebResult List<DTOObject> method() throws WebServiceException;

}
```

And let's say the DTO:

```
public class DTO {
   /*Attributes and DTO related stuff */
}
```

Then what I wanted to do was to export a JAR with the interface and the DTO classes so that all the client's could know the "interface stuff" by adding this "JAR-API" to the classpath and then just inject the Service Class and then CDI would know SOMEHOW that this is a webservice interface and each time it was called this would be forwarded to the Webservice endpoint and then wrapped back to my call stack.

Why I wanna do this? Because I am tired of everytime I change something in the DTO's or in the Webservice interface I have to do the whole WSIMPORT stuff in all client projects and that kills a lot of time!

I know this is possible, I've seen this in a old project somewhere I used to work at, that used Spring, but I don't know how to accomplish this with CDI and EJB3. Is it possible?

Thank you very much guys.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out myself after a couple of days searching.

For future reference and to help people that might find this question in the future here is how I solved the problem:

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/README.html

The whole idea is to Annotate the Impl Endpoint interface with both: @Stateless and @WebService

And in the client project after exposing the interface and the DTO's in a separate JAR file or link to folder in Eclipse do the following:

```
    Service calculatorService = Service.create(
                    new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4204/Calculator?wsdl"),
                    new QName("http://superbiz.org/wsdl", "CalculatorService"));

            CalculatorWs calculator = calculatorService.getPort(CalculatorWs.class);

/*Use your methods Freely!!*/
```